# How to convert weekly summed data to daily average in excel?

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have two columns with weekly summed data that look like this:

```
9/4/17    22.73
8/28/17   90.29
8/14/17   64.77
...
```

and I'd like to create new columns with missing days and the daily average for that week, for example:

```
9/4/17    3.25
9/3/17    3.25
9/2/17    3.25
9/1/17    3.25
...
```

Is there a quick way to do this calculation in Excel?

Comment: In my tiny world `9/4/17` is a Monday and `9/1/17` is a Friday... There are countries starting the week on Sundays or Mondays, but having it somewhere from Tuesday to Friday is new to me.... can you tell when to start?

Comment: I just used that as a brief example. The value should be '3.25' from 9/4/17 back to 8/29/17 and then change on 8/28/17.

Answer (score 0):

The fortnight gap for `weekly` values is confusing but if your dates are in ColumnA and you have series filled ColumnD with September 4 down to August 8 then in, say, E1 and copied down:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D1,A:A,-1))/7
```